# Deploying a django project on Hostmonster using FastCGI

Tags: django, url, fastcgi, hostmonster

I feel this might be a very simple question, but I am trying to learn to code using python/django so I can build some simple blog sites for my family and cannot get my site deployed on Hostmonster. I think I'm getting close, but I'm stuck with the following error:

> Using the URLconf defined in newproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>   ^admin/
>   The current URL, , didn't match any of these.`

I spent a bunch of time figuring out how to load python, django, etc. on my shared HostMonster account, and thought I had it all figured out when I loaded a generic, unmodified django `newproject` and got the django "It worked!" screen, but as soon as I uncommented the lines in urls.py and settings.py to enable the admin module, I get stuck with the above error.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mysite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /mysite/jarr.fcgi [QSA,L]
```

and here is my `jarr.fcgi` file:

```
#!/home3/usr/python/bin/python
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, "/home3/usr/django/django_projects/newproject")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home3/usr/python")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home3/usr/python/lib")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home3/usr/python/lib/python2.7")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home3/usr/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home3/usr/django/django_src")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "newproject.settings"
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

So frustrating to finally get the "It worked!" from my hostmonster account after weeks of work, but then I can't even enable the admin let alone build an actual site, which is so easy on my local machine.  Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to get a solution for this? I am facing the same problem with godaddy shared hosting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310086/django-on-shared-hosting-setup-issue-404-for-the-admin-url-urls-py-being-ignor

Answer (score 2):

I have created an example django project for you, which can be easily hosted on shared hosting providers. You can find it on github - https://github.com/psjinx/django-example-project-shared-hosting.

I have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14398734/353550) a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310086/django-on-shared-hosting-setup-issue-404-for-the-admin-url-urls-py-being-ignor) asked by [alok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41284/alok), you may look into that as well.

If you are still having some issues then please post them in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Note the error message:

```
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.`
```

This means Django isn't getting any URI information. The reason is this line:

```
 RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mysite/jarr.fcgi [QSA,L]
```

Note that the only thing that can cause the `fcgi` script to be called is visiting the "index", and even then no URI information is given.
You'll want your `RewriteRule` to be something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite/jarr.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

(important part is the `/$1`)

Try moving the `jarr.fgci` to the public "root" of your domain (ie, not under `mysite`) and change your rule to be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ jarr.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

You'll still be able to put files in the directory to be served directly by apache.